# Is it possible to connect to Webpshere MQ?

Tags: queue, jms, ibm-mq

I am having an incredibly difficult time finding any information by IBM on how to connect to our company's queue. Some more specific questions:

- do I need the queue manage?
- how do I know which queue connection factory to use?
- how do I connect to the queue from a standalone java application?

I honestly can't find any MODERN, up-to-date resources explaining the websphere mq and how to make use of it (this includes within my own company).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to a queue manager in either binding mode or client mode. Binding mode allows an application to connect to the queue manager only when they are both running on the same machine. Client mode allows an application to connect to the queue manager when the two a running on separate machines. You can use client mode when they are both running on the same machine but its not as efficient as binding mode.

If you want to use binding mode then you only need to know the queue manager name.

If you want to use client mode then you will need to know the queue manager name, hostname, listener port number, and channel name.

The following URL provides some information on using JMS to connect to MQ:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031500_.htm